how i can use search delegate correctly
i create search icon in appbar to open search and when i click on it there is error appear
the error is "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator"
and it's my code
void main() {
  runApp(rekomo2());
}

class rekomo2 extends StatefulWidget {
  rekomo2({super.key});

  @override
  State<rekomo2> createState() => _rekomo2State();
}
class _rekomo2State extends State<rekomo2> {
  int curindex = 0;
  
  final screen = [chats(), groups(), nearme(), status(), favourite()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

        //  routes: {"nearme": (context) => nearme()},
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MaterialApp(
            
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                    onPressed: () {
                      //  showSearch(context: context , delegate: search(),);
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              appBar: AppBar(
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showSearch(context: context, delegate: search());
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: Colors.purple[300]))
                ],
                leading: Builder(
                    builder: (context) => IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                          color: Colors.purple[300],
                        )),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                title: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Rekomo2",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.purple[300]),
                    ),
                    
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                  currentIndex: curindex,
                  onTap: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      curindex = value;
                    });
                  },
                  selectedItemColor: Colors.purple[600],
                  // currentIndex: screen[Key.],
                  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                  showSelectedLabels: true,
                  showUnselectedLabels: false,
                  items: const [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: "Chats"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                      label: "Groups",
                    ),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined), label: "People Near Me"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.switch_access_shortcut_sharp), label: "Status"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: "Favourite"),
                  ]),
              //  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              drawer: const Drawer(),
              body: screen[curindex],
            )));
  }
}

class search extends SearchDelegate {
  List searchr = ["devil", "karma", "reem", "ahmed", "moaa"];
  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.close))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.search));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("data");
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      return Text("");
    } else {
      List filterlist = searchr.where((element) => element.contains(query)).toList();
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: filterlist.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return InkWell(onTap: () => context, child: Card(child: Text(filterlist[i])));
        },
      );
    }
  }
}

and i don't know what cause the error and how to fix it
and i try to use search delegate with floating button but the same error appear

the error disappear after add builder and hero code :
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Builder(builder: (context) {
                return FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: 'searchBtn',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                  onPressed: () {
                    showSearch(
                      context: context,
                      delegate: search(),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                );
              }),
              Container(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 'addBtn',
                backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showSearch(context: context, delegate: search());
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: Colors.purple[300]),
                ),
              )
            ],
            leading: Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                      color: Colors.purple[300],
                    )),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Rekomo2",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.purple[300]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: curindex,
              onTap: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  curindex = value;
                });
              },
              selectedItemColor: Colors.purple[600],
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              showSelectedLabels: true,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: "Chats"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                  label: "Groups",
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined), label: "People Near Me"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.switch_access_shortcut_sharp), label: "Status"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: "Favourite"),
              ]),
          drawer: const Drawer(),
          body: screen[curindex],
        ));
  }
}

class search extends SearchDelegate {
  List searchr = ["devil", "karma", "reem", "ahmed", "moaa"];
  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.close))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.search));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("data");
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      return Text("");
    } else {
      List filterlist = searchr.where((element) => element.contains(query)).toList();
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: filterlist.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return InkWell(onTap: () => context, child: Card(child: Text(filterlist[i])));
        },
      );
    }
  }
}



I have reviewed your code and found that you were trying to use the showSearch function with a context that does not have a Navigator in its widget tree.
In your code, you are using a nested MaterialApp, which can lead to issues. There should only be one MaterialApp at the root of your widget tree. Here’s how you can fix your code:

Remove the nested MaterialApp.
Use showSearch with the correct context.

I have modified your code with some additions, feel free to makes changes and see if it works.
Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Rekomo2());
}

class Rekomo2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Rekomo2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Rekomo2> createState() => _Rekomo2State();
}

class _Rekomo2State extends State<Rekomo2> {
  int curindex = 0;
  final screen = [Chats(), Groups(), NearMe(), Status(), Favourite()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search());
              },
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search());
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: Colors.purple[300])),
          ],
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
              color: Colors.purple[300],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(
            "Rekomo2",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.purple[300]),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: curindex,
          onTap: (value) {
            setState(() {
              curindex = value;
            });
          },
          selectedItemColor: Colors.purple[600],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: "Chats"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.group), label: "Groups"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined), label: "People Near Me"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.switch_access_shortcut_sharp), label: "Status"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), label: "Favourite"),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: const Drawer(),
        body: screen[curindex],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends SearchDelegate {
  List searchResults = ["devil", "karma", "reem", "ahmed", "moaa"];

  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(query));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestions = query.isEmpty
        ? []
        : searchResults.where((element) => element.contains(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(suggestions[index]),
          onTap: () {
            query = suggestions[index];
            showResults(context);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Chats extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Chats'));
  }
}

class Groups extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Groups'));
  }
}

class NearMe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('People Near Me'));
  }
}

class Status extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Status'));
  }
}

class Favourite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Favourite'));
  }
}


i remove the material app but it doesn't work and show me the same error "The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget."
